# How to setup xcode to Automate App using APpium

Tags: xcode, appium, appium-ios

I am new to ios App Automation and i am struggling to setup xcode to automate ios App using APpium.Developers has distributed the App via TestFlight and i am struggling to setup xcode configuration to access my installed app in ios device using APpium.
Based on available online resource i did setup but still getting below error

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message:`

This issue is because of xcode setup or some other reason.Below is the capabilities which i have added,

```
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "14.7.1");
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone");
    caps.setCapability("udid", <device udid>);
    caps.setCapability("app", <bundleId>);
    caps.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", <xcodeOrgId>);
    caps.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", <xcodeSigningId>);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say where the issue is exactly because of missing details and appium logs. But I can guess that the issue is somewhere in the WebDriverAgent application signing (usually 65 errors caused by this reason). If you're new and trying to run the test on the real device I'm almost sure that the issue is in the WDA signing.

What could I suggest to do:

1. Try to follow the next tutorial and set up the WDA Xcode project manually.
   https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/ -> **Full manual configuration**
2. Remove the xcodeOrgId and xcodeSigningId since WDA will be already configured
3. Check that device UDID is added to the Apple developer team's list if you're using the real device not a simulator